# How to split a NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, split, nsattributedstring

I imported a NSAttributedString from a rtf-file and now I want to split it at another given String. With the `attributedSubstring` method you get one attributedSubstring as result, but I want to split it at every part, where the other String appeares, so the result should be an Array of NSAttributedStrings.
Example:
`var source = NSAttributedString(string: "I*** code*** with*** swift")
 var splitter = "***"
 var array = //The method I am looking for`

The result should be the following Array(with attributedStrings): [I, code, with, swift]

Comment: See `attributedSubstring`.

Comment: I can't find the class, in which package is it? Not in Foundation or CoreText, if I did not miss anything

Comment: It a method of `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1414283-attributedsubstringfromrange?language=objc ?

Comment: With the attributedSubstring method I can only get the substring in a given range, but I want to split it. Do I have to use NSRange in a special way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following extension method maps the string components using `Array.map` into `[NSAttributedString]`

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func components(separatedBy string: String) -> [NSAttributedString] {
        var pos = 0
        return self.string.components(separatedBy: string).map {
            let range = NSRange(location: pos, length: $0.count)
            pos += range.length + string.count
            return self.attributedSubstring(from: range)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let array = NSAttributedString(string: "I*** code*** with*** swift").components(separatedBy: "***")
```